# Compression in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I read this article but I wonder how the 3 steps as mentioned in it are done,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-compression/page-compression-implementation?view=sql-server-2017

Do they mean `Row Compression` is done first then the row-compressed data are spoon-fed to `Prefix` then `Dictionary`?
When I `dbcc` the page, I can't see things as what they tell. They would likely be cheating readers.

Comment: It's unclear what you're specifically asking for that isn't covered by the documentation you've linked to.

Comment: The article is misinforming readers.

Comment: Do you have a *script* that you can share with us that *demonstrates* your assertion?